# ¿Cómo saber cuántas veces se dice un nombre en una lista, en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo una lista con 50mil socios en un archivo .csv. Lo leo con un `bufferedReader` y en un bucle voy armando objetos de las personas con sus atributos (nombre, equipo simpatizante, estudios, estado civil), luego los meto en una lista.

```java
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivo/socios.csv")); // leo el archivo
String line = br.readLine();
while (null!=line) {
    String [] fields = line.split(SEPARATOR);


    fields = removeTrailingQuotes(fields);


    Socio socio = new Socio();  // armo un objeto para poder manipular sus atributos y lo seteo con los datos leidos
    socio.setNombre(fields[0]);
    socio.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(fields[1]));
    socio.setEquipo(fields[2]);
    socio.setEstadoCivil(fields[3]);
    socio.setNivelEstudios(fields[4]);
```

Ahora bien, tengo una lista con 50mil socios y necesito saber los nombres más comunes de los socios de River, para ello he separado los socios de River en otra lista.

```
if(fields[2].equals("River")) {
    listaSociosRiver.add(socio);
}
```

Ahora tengo una lista completamente de socios de River que se ve así:

[image: Lista Socios de River]

Mi pregunta aquí es: ¿cómo puedo verificar qué cantidad de veces aparece cada nombre y cuáles se repiten más?

Tengo entendido que debo hacer un bucle que vaya comparando uno por uno un nombre con todos los nombres que hay dentro, y si se encuentra ir sumando una variable pero no logro descifrar cómo.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Lo bonito de la programación es que se puede probar y nada estalla (en un entorno de desarollo adecuado). Prueba y trae tu problema específico. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: La más fácil: Lleva una lista de nombres y vas contando. Supongo que el campo nombre tiene nombre y apellido; te corresponde separar cada uno de forma adecuada (considerando el caso de un solo nombre o cuatro para los más italianos-de-cuna) y buscar si está en tu lista y sumarle 1 al conteo. Si te sientes elegante y listaSociosLista hereda de Collections, puedes usar stream para recorrerla

Comment: con un diccionario cuya clave sea el nombre, es mucho mas facil tambien ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiero que uses un diccionario. En Java lo más cercano que tienes es la interfaz [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Una de las clases que la implementa es [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Entonces tendrías uno así:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Y vas iterando sobre los socios agregando sus nombres como claves si no están y vas sumando 1 a su valor.

```
// Suponiendo que en la variable socio tienes una instancia
// y con getName puedes obtener su nombre
int cantidad = map.getOrDefault(socio.getName(), 0);
map.put(socio.getName(), cantidad + 1);
```

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme! Me tira un error en getOrDefault, por lo que leo es porque no admite un String de parámetro (socio.getName()). 

Luego de esto, como hago para mostrar los mas comunes?

Comment: no le fatla ,0 al getOrDefault? y luego, no deberias sumar 1 a la cantidad?

Comment: @gbianchi si, creí que lo había puesto. Gracias por notarlo.

Comment: @Damsh para mostrar los más comunes tienes varias opciones. Si optas por ordenarlo, aquí hay varios ejemplos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13913206

Comment: y no tenes que sumarle 1?? si no, siempre guardas la misma cantidad...

Comment: @gbianchi menos mal que estás en todas.

Comment: @Mateo estoy teniendo problemas para iterar sobre los socios, he hecho un for que vaya hasta el size de la listaSociosRiver y dentro del for he metido tu codigo pero incrementa a cantidad infinitas veces, no logro seguir avanzando

Comment: ¿Y si usa un Set, con eso no repite elementos? Acá echando globos :D

Comment: @Alfabravo Set es una interfaz. Necesitas una clase que la implemente.

Comment: @Mateo lo sé bien, pero _cualquier implementación de Set_ tiene por característica evitar las repeticiones, que le vendría bien al caso del OP :) Ya queda elegir de acuerdo a lo que se quiera usar. Por ejemplo, un HashSet