# ¿Cómo agrupar datos mediante un valor en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo.csv con 50mil socios de diferentes equipos de futbol, el archivo se ve algo así. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para leerlo hago un bucle en un bufferedReader y meto toda la informacion en un Array.

```
try { 
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("archivo/socios.csv")); // leo el archivo
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (null!=line) {
        String [] fields = line.split(SEPARATOR);
            
            
        fields = removeTrailingQuotes(fields);
           
            
        Socio socio = new Socio();  // armo un objeto para poder manipular sus atributos y lo seteo con los datos leidos
        socio.setNombre(fields[0]);
        socio.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(fields[1]));
        socio.setEquipo(fields[2]);
        socio.setEstadoCivil(fields[3]);
        socio.setNivelEstudios(fields[4]);
```

Ahora bien, necesito separar en un listado ordenado de mayor a menor, todos los equipos, con sus hinchas totales y el promedio de edad total de los hinchas de cada club, algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿De qué forma puedo lograrlo?

Comment: Cada socio en un Array? es que no se muestra en tu código, si esta en un array puedes iterar en todos los elementos y calcular los totales

Comment: Puedes usar [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)) pasando el arreglo y un comparador. Estás diciendo lo mismo que en tu [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/511230/16974) pero con algunos cambios. Te invito a qué investigues, intentes y no escribas código de una parte que no tiene que ver con tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero esta manera. Pero es valida de java 8 y mas actual.

```
private List<String> lineas;
    
        @Override
    public void cargarArchivo(String direccion){
        lineas = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Path ruta = Paths.get(direccion);
            Stream<String> flujoFormateado = Files.lines(ruta, Charset.defaultCharset());
            flujoFormateado.forEach(lineas::add); // almacenando todos los elementos para su analisis

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ArchivosServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


    }
```

Para tomar tu ejemplo esto es una manera de hacerlo.

> Collectors.groupingBy

```
String linea = "Juan;jose;Ramon;guerra;Juan;Ramon ";
        String [] fields = linea.split(";");
Arrays.asList(fields).stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::valueOf)).forEach((k,v) -> {
            System.out.println("Clave: "+k+" Cantidad: "+v.size());
            v.forEach(System.out::println);
        });
```

Salidas:

```
Clave: Ramon  Cantidad: 1
Ramon 
Clave: jose Cantidad: 1
jose
Clave: guerra Cantidad: 1
guerra
Clave: Juan Cantidad: 2
Juan
Juan
Clave: Ramon Cantidad: 1
Ramon
```

Profundiza un poco mas y encontraras como concretar tu codigo.